# Code Composer Studio error

Tags: msp430, code-composer

I am a new user to Code Composer but I have an average knowledge of C and C++ coding.
I have done some arduino and ATmel mega (standalone) projects and now I took it to the next step by starting to create a project with the MSP430Launchpad.

So I have created a header file .h and where I have some defines and I have named the functions I am going to use and a source .c file where I have declared and written the functions.

I imported the the header file throught the build options and the c file through the add files option.

Now when I cal a simple function in my main and built my project I get these errors [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ive6a.jpg)

Comment: How are you including that header file in your main.c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems are coming from not including the .c files where return_x and exp430RfSpiInit are mentioned in your CCS project as well; the header files mention return_x and exp430RfSpiInit in main, but the linker file doesn't know where they are relative to the CCS project. Right click on your project in CCS -> Add Files -> add the .c files to your CCS project.